# Safer way to use dd

Tags: dd

I need to write a .bin file directly to a USB (as boot sector opcodes), however, I don't like using the "**d**isk **d**estroyer" command from the terminal.

Is there a safer way to use dd?

Comment: Any utility can be unsafe if you aren't paying attention.  I once used Norton GHOST to clone a disk, but accidentally wrote the empty disk onto the one with data.

Comment: dd is totally safe. Users on the other hand...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `dd` is a terminal program you can't easily see what you're doing, so if you're not paying attention it's easy to make a mistake that overwrites the wrong partition or drive. Even the smallest of typing errors can make `dd` into a disk destroyer. Using a graphical front-end to `dd` is a safer way to use `dd`.

Gdiskdump is a open source graphical user interface for `dd`. You can easily select the input and output stream, so you can clone or image your hard drive or partition. .tar.gz and .deb files are available at the [gdiskdump GitHub](https://github.com/screenfreeze/gdiskdump) website.

**Installation in Debian-based systems**

```
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/screenfreeze/gdiskdump.git
cd gdiskdump/deb/  && sudo dpkg -i *.deb # latest version is gdiskdump_0.8-1_all.deb
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, and I'll try the other method as well.

Answer (score 3):

If your OS distribution supports it, consider using the `/dev/disk/` symlinks instead of the `/dev/sd*` devices directly. For example, instead of:

```
# Was sda the right one? Or do I need to use sda1?
dd if=disk.img of=/dev/sda
```

You can use:

```
# Overwrite the partition with the label "OldStuff"
dd if=disk.img of=/dev/disk/by-partlabel/OldStuff
```

or

```
# Overwrite the first partition of my 3GB Seagate drive
dd if=disk.img of=/dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST3000DM001-1ER166_W5009B5W-part1
```

or

```
# Write to the drive plugged into USB
dd if=disk.img of=/dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:0a:00.0-usb-0:1:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0
```